# How do I use multiple variable from one function into another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to call a, b in function add, I get a is not defined even though I am returning the values. How do I make it return both a and b?

```
def numbers():
        a= input ("a:")
        a = int(a)
        b= input ("b:")
        b = int(b)
        return a
        return b
    
def add():
    numbers()
    print (a)
    print (b)
add()
```

Comment: There are two separate problems in the code. The first is the linked duplicate. The second is that functions **return values, not variables**. Within `add`, the result from the `numbers()` call needs to be assigned to local names, or else used directly. Calling `numbers()` **does not** create local `a` and `b` variables. The error message only complains about `a` because the error causes the program to terminate; there is no opportunity to complain about `b`, but it would if it got that far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `return` statement almost always causes a function to immediately terminate, and no other statement in the function will run. So once you return `a`, you'll never get to `return b`. You need to return both of them at the same time.

Additionally, returning a value from a function will not automatically put those names into the scope that called the function. You need to manually assign the values to something.

```
def numbers():
       a= input ("a:")
       a = int(a)
       b= input ("b:")
       b = int(b)
       return a,b

def add():
    a,b = numbers()
    print (a)
    print (b)

add()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am doing python for a class but I don't have a good basic knowledge. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think so:

```
def numbers():
        a= input ("a:")
        a = int(a)
        b= input ("b:")
        b = int(b)
        return a, b

def add(a, b):
    print (a)
    print (b)
    return a, b

def main():
    another_a, another_b = numbers()
    another_a, another_b = add(another_a, another_b)

main()
```